# Prevent word from opening when opening a document

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I want to open several documents in my application, but when doing so, Word always opens the main window. How can I prevent this from happening?

I already set the visibility of both the application and the document to `false`, but it still opens when I start my program.

```
private static readonly Application word = new Application();

[...]

FileInfo fileInfo = (FileInfo)file;

object filename = fileInfo.FullName;
object confirmConversion = false;
object readOnly = true;
object visible = false;
object skipEncodingDialog = true;
object save = false;

word.Visible = false;

Document srcDoc = word.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref confirmConversion, ref readOnly, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref visible,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref skipEncodingDialog, ref missing);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application word = new Application(); represent one word window.

```
private void OpenWord(string path)
{
Application word = new Application();
FileInfo fileInfo = (FileInfo)file;

object filename = fileInfo.FullName;
object confirmConversion = false;
object readOnly = true;
object visible = false;
object skipEncodingDialog = true;
object save = false;

word.Visible = false;

Document srcDoc = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref confirmConversion, ref readOnly, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref visible,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref skipEncodingDialog, ref missing);
}
```